# Unnecessary url

Tags: urls

```
$alt_text = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$output .= '<div class="pslide"><a href="' . $alt_text . '"><img src="' . $img_attr[0] . '" /></a></div>';
```

With the code i can get an image and alt text as url for each slide in my slider. Everything works just fine but unfortunately when i move my mouse over the image i can see something like this:
192.168.1.100/wordpress/www.youtube.com

How can i get rid of wordpress url ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always include `http://` in your URLs. Change `www.youtube.com` in `http://www.youtube.com/` or even better `http://youtube.com/`

If you forget the `http://` then the data is being parsed like it is another page on your website rather than an external website, that's why you'll see `192.168.1.100/wordpress/www.youtube.com`